# DateTime TimeZone handling on client and server side

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, kendo-datepicker, kendo-datetimepicker

My application has an option to the customer where he/she can set a timezone in which he/she wants to work/view the application in.

Overall idea of the application workflow is, client should send the datetime as per user selected timezone (server assumes this), server converts this datetime to UTC (server knows which timezone is selected on the client application), server performs all operations in UTC and then stores the datetime in UTC. Just before returning the control from server to client, server converts the UTC datetime to user selected timezone.

Client and server has a handshake on the datetime string format "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss". Server parses this string and converts into appropriate DateTime object.

Please let me know your thoughts on above workflow, and if there is any other better or standard way of achieving this.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're only selecting a *date*, then you can just pass the value as `yyyy-MM-dd`, without time zones being relevant. What have you got so far with Kendo? What's going wrong? It's not very clear what you're asking at the moment.

Comment: But if the user is just picking a date and time, and Kendo can provide your script with that date and time, I don't think it really matters whether that's been done "via" a local time zone. Again: what have you got so far, and what goes wrong?

Comment: Thanks Jon. I guess I was running around in circles with kendo :) and figured out an alternative way to achieve what I exactly want. Edited my question above (removed kendo query part, sorry about that). However, would still like to know for above requirement, am I on the correct path and following the best/standard practice? What do you think Jon?

Comment: Well, whether or not you should store the value in UTC or in the local time is a difficult one, which depends on the application. Don't assume that UTC is *always* the way to go. But at this point the question is a bit too broad for SO, in my view.